# Automated Google query with excel vba: Can anyone get this to work?

Tags: excel, vba

new to the community and looking for a way to perform google searches automated with excel vba and  then parse for the "About 49,600 results (0.78 seconds)" information just below the header. I recently found this tutorial that seems to (or claims to) accomplish just that. --> http://yodalearning.com/tutorials/perform-google-search-internet-explorer-using-excel-vba-excel-vba/

Can anyone get this to work?

when I try to run the module it open Google but then does nothing with the load circle going for an eternity. If anyone has ideas on how to get this to work any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @pnuts LOL - I love the "If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question." portion of the [seo] tag description.

Comment: This tag is a dumpster fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following in A2:A4

```
girafe
rhino
starbucks
```

Run the script below.

```
Sub Gethits()
    Dim url As String, lastRow As Long
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResultDiv As Object, objH3 As Object, link As Object
    Dim start_time As Date
    Dim end_time As Date
    Dim var As String
    Dim var1 As Object

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cookie As String
    Dim result_cookie As String

    start_time = Time
    Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
        Set objResultDiv = html.getelementbyid("rso")
        Set var1 = html.getelementbyid("resultStats")
        Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText

        DoEvents
    Next

    end_time = Time
    Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

    Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
    MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
End Sub
```

Mozilla:
[image]

Comment: You are awesome, this works like a dream. Thank you for your help :D

Comment: If you define your question well, it's easy to define an answer well.

Comment: After playing around with it, I tried running a large list of 200 or so keyword searches through the module and I ran into a strange error that happens after running through 50 to 70 (it varies) keywords. The Debug highlights "Cells(i, 2).Value = var1.innerText" as the error and a dialog box that says "Run time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set". It seems strange that it would run just fine until a certain amount of queries. I understand that Google stops queries if an IP is spamming in short time, but I have no way of finding out if that is the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried 150 randome word searches and I couldn't even get one to work.  I'm in the office now.  I'm guessing the firm's firewallblocs all these things  Normally it's not a good idea to use 'On Error Resume Next' but in this case it's probably ok.  Put that line near the top of your script and re-run the porcess.  Maybe Google can't find what you're looking for, and it returns nothing, which causes the error.  That's just a guess.  I can't tell for sure.

Comment: "On Error Resume Next" didn't do much of anything besides stop the error box from popping up. After the first error it wouldn't even run the module again without an error. I left my prior network IP and tried it again on a separate network IP and it allowed about 45 queries before the error occurred again. This leads me to believe that Google is sensing a security issue and blocking the IP after so many queries. Again no way to test it for sure but that's my guess. Let me know if you run into a similar issue on a network other than the one you tried it on without luck. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I am home now, and out of curiosity I just tested it to see what's going on.  I ran through 400 items in 4 minutes, with no issues whatsoever.  Then, I tested 1,200 items, just for fun.  It ran to completion in 23 minutes.  I don't know what's going on over on your end.  I'm not a professional developer, by any means.  I just dabble in this stuff when I'm not working, or playing chess.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! It's curious that it works so well on yours, but also good news. Makes me wonder, do you know if you have multiple proxies set up? Just been doing some research to see what issues might be. I'm no developer either. I just need something like this for work day to day and having it Excel is great for workflow.

Comment: I added an image of my Mozilla proxy settings to my OP.  Does that help you?  I'm getting about to the limit of my knowledge in this specific area.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I am not sure what that would do but thank you. Sorry to go off track so much. To bring it back to VBA, would there be a way to make it so that each query is run on a timed interval? For example, the the script runs the query on the first word in the list and spits out a result but then waits a specified amount of seconds before running the next keyword in the list. The reason for this is that overloading servers with quick, back-to-back queries is suspicious and Google likes to block these types of scrapers. Do you know if its possible to do this?

Comment: I was going to recommend that a couple days ago, but I got sidetracked with something, and then I forgot.  You could try this, to wait 5 seconds between loops:  
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
I'm not sure if that would solve the problem, but you can try and see.  Obviously that will add 5  seconds to your completion time, times the number of loops you run.  If the objective is to get it to finish, and if speed isn't a concern, try that.  Fire it off, then go get some food, or whatever, and see if it's done when you get back to your machine.